# JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature using next-auth, nextjs and vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt, vercel, next-auth

for some reason I have a weird error regarding api requests. As the title says JWT doesn't verify my token, but I send headers with `authorization` that I take from `next-auth's session.user.accessToken`. In my other applications everything works fine(they are verifying JWT token in the same way). In this application the error only appears in production, in development everything works as expected. I tried to log out and log in again. Inside next-auth I use `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` and inside JWT functions `SECRET_KEY`, these two are different keys but the same in production and development. Here is my code:

EDIT: The error only appears only when hosted on vercel.

```
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {label: "email", type:"email", placeholder: "name@example.com"},
        password: {label: "password", type: "password", placeholder:"password"}
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const res = await fetch(envCheck()+"/api/login", {
          method:"POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({
            email: credentials?.email,
            password: credentials?.password,
          })
        });
        console.log("response from authorize",res); // Will show you the status
        if(res.status === 200) {
          const user = res.json();
          return user;
        } else {
          throw new Error(""+res.status);
        }
      },
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth',
    signOut: '/'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, user, trigger, session}) {
      if(trigger === "update") {
        return {...token, ...session.user}
      }
      return({...token, ...user})
    },
    async session({session, token}) {
      session.user = token as any;
      return session;
    }
  }
}
```

```
interface SignOption {
  expiresIn?: string | number;

}

const DEFAULT_SIGN_OPTION: SignOption = {
  expiresIn: "1h"
}

export function signJwtAccessToken(payload: JwtPayload, options?:SignOption) {
  const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
  const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret_key!, options);

  return token;
}

export function verifyJwt(token:string) {
  try {
    const secret_key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret_key!);
    
    return decoded as JwtPayload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Request example:

```
const response = await fetch(envCheck()+`/api/user/${session?.user.id}/gym`, {
  headers:{
    "authorization": session.user.accessToken,
  },
});
```

Validating token:

```
const accessToken = request.headers.get("authorization")
  if(!accessToken || !verifyJwt(accessToken)) {
    return NextResponse.json("401");
  };
```